# How to extract lines from a textfile that contains string from a list in another file in order of search list?

Tags: awk, grep

File 1: sourcefile.txt

```
Hello, It's the beginning of the sentence. 
it is the beginpoint of my career.
The end is always far.
We can start our beginpoint anytime we want.
The time we utilise to make our life good should be more.
This text doesn't mean anything.
I am writing this to include my three points:
beginpoint
time
end
```

File 2: strings.txt

```
beginpoint
end
time
```

Required output:

```
it is the beginpoint of my career
We can start our beginpoint anytime we want.
beginpoint
The end is always far.
end
The time we utilise to make our life good should be more.
time
```

I used

```
grep -w -F -f  strings.txt sorcefile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

I got output:

```
it is the beginpoint of my career.
The end is always far.
We can start our beginpoint anytime we want.
The time we utilise to make our life good should be more.
beginpoint
time
end
```

So the lines are as needed but i want to group them by the search term order and not in the same order as the source file

Comment: Repost of [How to extract lines from a textfile that contains string from a list in another file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591049/how-to-extract-lines-from-a-textfile-that-contains-string-from-a-list-in-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to call `grep` once per each line of `strings.txt`

```
$ while IFS= read -r line; do grep -wF "$line" sourcefile.txt; done < strings.txt
it is the beginpoint of my career.
We can start our beginpoint anytime we want.
beginpoint
The end is always far.
end
The time we utilise to make our life good should be more.
time
```

If the `strings.txt` file is too long, this will can be slow, see 
[Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

With `sed` if it supports `e` flag:

```
$ sed 's/.*/grep -wF '"'&'"' sourcefile.txt/e' strings.txt
it is the beginpoint of my career.
We can start our beginpoint anytime we want.
beginpoint
The end is always far.
end
The time we utilise to make our life good should be more.
time
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list of strings doesn't contain spaces as in your example:

```
$ awk -F'[^[:alnum:]_]+' '
    NR==FNR { strs[$0]; next }
    { for (str in strs) for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==str) print str, FNR, $0 }
' file2 file1 | sort -k1,1 -k2,2n | cut -d' ' -f3-
it is the beginpoint of my career.
We can start our beginpoint anytime we want.
beginpoint
The end is always far.
end
The time we utilise to make our life good should be more.
time
```

The above works by not only printing the line that contains the matching string but also the string that was matched plus the line number it was matched on (to retain relative order after sorting - not necessary if we used GNU sort for `-s`) then sorting and then removing the adornments that were added in step one. Here it is step by step:

```
$ awk -F'[^[:alnum:]_]+' 'NR==FNR{strs[$0];next} {for (str in strs) for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==str) print str, FNR, $0}' file2 file1
beginpoint 2 it is the beginpoint of my career.
end 3 The end is always far.
beginpoint 4 We can start our beginpoint anytime we want.
time 5 The time we utilise to make our life good should be more.
beginpoint 8 beginpoint
time 9 time
end 10 end
```

.

```
$ awk -F'[^[:alnum:]_]+' 'NR==FNR{strs[$0];next} {for (str in strs) for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==str) print str, FNR, $0}' file2 file1 | sort -k1,1 -k2,2n
beginpoint 2 it is the beginpoint of my career.
beginpoint 4 We can start our beginpoint anytime we want.
beginpoint 8 beginpoint
end 3 The end is always far.
end 10 end
time 5 The time we utilise to make our life good should be more.
time 9 time
```

.

```
$ awk -F'[^[:alnum:]_]+' 'NR==FNR{strs[$0];next} {for (str in strs) for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==str) print str, FNR, $0}' file2 file1 |
    sort -k1,1 -k2,2n | cut -d' ' -f3-
it is the beginpoint of my career.
We can start our beginpoint anytime we want.
beginpoint
The end is always far.
end
The time we utilise to make our life good should be more.
time
```